# oratcl ORA-24338: statement handle not executed

Tags: oracle, tcl

Simple example using oratcl:

## Create Table and simple package

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER,val INTEGER);
INSERT INTO test (id,val) values (1,10);
INSERT INTO test (id,val) values (2,20);
INSERT INTO test (id,val) values (3,30);
INSERT INTO test (id,val) values (4,40);


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  tst is
  FUNCTION get_test RETURN sys_refcursor;
END; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE  PACKAGE BODY tst is
  FUNCTION get_test  RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   retval sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN retval FOR SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id;
 RETURN retval;
END;
END;
/
```

## Tcl functions are below:

```
package require Oratcl

proc getLoginStr {} {
   set userName  "xxx"
   set password  "xxxx"
   set db        "xxx"
   append retval  $userName "/" $password "@" $db
}

set _lda ""
set _sqlH ""

proc init {} {
  global _lda
  global _sqlH
 set _lda [oralogon [getLoginStr]]
 set _sqlH [oraopen $_lda]
}

proc prepare {} {
  global _sqlH
  set Sql {
         begin
             :retval := tst.get_test();
         end;                   
 }

 ::db_ora::parseSql $_sqlH $Sql 
}

proc go {} {
  global _lda
  global _sqlH

  set curH [oraopen $_lda]
  set pv_lst [list :retval $curH] 

  orabind $_sqlH  :retval $curH
  oraexec $_sqlH

  set retval ""

  while {[orafetch $curH -datavariable row] == 0} {
    puts "row : $row" 
    lappend retval  $row
  }
return $retval
}
```

## Run following script once:

```
source test.tcl
init
prepare
go
```

### Output:

```
row : 1 10
row : 2 20
row : 3 30
row : 4 40
{1 10} {2 20} {3 30} {4 40}
```

## re-Run go procedure

```
go
```

### Output:

```
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
row : 
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
```

Any Ideas? Why script did not work on re-run? If I am not mistaken it should reuse the opened handle _SqlH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need tcl to see this behavior. You can reproduce this with plain SQL. Once you have iterated over the `sys_refcursor` that has been returned by `tst.get_test()`, you cannot "rewind" it and iterate again.

Consult the docs on how to use ref_cursors (10.2) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7106

So in this current form, you can only run the tcl `go`again after you also run `prepare` again.

Comment: Ok. Looks like you are right :) I thought that oratcl will take care of closing cursor with some kind of Magic :).